# Calculate the GCD of two numbers recursively with javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

I have a `calculator` function to calculate the `GCD` of two numbers here, i got a problem changing it to make it calculate the gcd `rcursively` using the following rules:
`if y is zero then x is the gcd`, else `the gcd is always the gcd of y and remainder of x/y` ..
Here is the code that needs changing

```
function calculator(x,y){
    let r=x%y;
    while(r!=0){
        x=y;
        y=r;
        r=x%y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: have you tried the given rules? what does not work?

Comment: Its not homework, am trying to understand recursion with javascript

Comment: You pretty much described the algorithm in your question: `gcd(x, y) if y == 0 /* if y is zero then x is the gcd */ return ?; else /* the gcd is always the gcd of y and remainder of x/y */ return gcd(?, ?);`. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: I'm guessing you could easily find this answer by searching here on StackOverflow or on the wider web, but this is a fairly simple recursion: `const gcd = (x, y) => y == 0 ? x : gcd (y, x % y)`.  If you also want to handle negative integers, `const gcd = (x, y) => y < 0 ? gcd (x, - y) : y == 0 ? x : gcd (y, x % y)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the words:

- if y is zero then x is the gcd,
- else the gcd is always the gcd of y and remainder of x/y

```js
function gcd(x, y) {
    if (y === 0) return x;
    /* else */ return gcd(y, x % y);
}

console.log(gcd(27, 12)); // 3
console.log(gcd(12, 27)); // 3
```